# Can this ratio of weight vectors be simplified to one line?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, covariance, ratio

$$\frac{\boldsymbol w' \boldsymbol\sigma}{\boldsymbol{w' \Sigma w}}$$

Can the ratio above be simplified to one line, given that the weights could cancel somehow? $\boldsymbol{w}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times 1}$ is a vector, $\boldsymbol\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is the covariance matrix, and $\boldsymbol\sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times 1}$ is a vector of the elements $\sqrt{\text{diag}(\boldsymbol\Sigma)}$.

Comment: Cholesky factorization $\Sigma=C'C$ (possible because $\Sigma$ is a positive definite matrix) gives the denominator a simpler form $(Cw)'(Cw)=\|Cw\|^2$ but is it what you want ?

Comment: trying to put it in a non-ratio form if possible

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "given that the weights could cancel somehow"

Comment: In full, your fraction can be written as 
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_{i,i} w_i}{\sum_{i,j=1}^N \sigma_{i,j} w_i w_j}
$$

Comment: you don't understand canceling? there is one weight vector in the numerator, and two of the same weight vector in the denominator